# Не работает сохранение в БД ADO

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

Не получается сохранить изменения сделанные в datagridview в базу данных.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataTable dbTable = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter dbAdp = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand dbCmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();                
    }

public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=wpl27.hosting.reg.ru; Initial Catalog=u1236799_BallOSP5; User ID=****;Password=****");
    sqlConn.Open();
    dbAdp.SelectCommand = dbCmd;
    dbAdp.Fill(dbTable);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dbTable;
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns[7].Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;               
}

private void SaveupdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=wpl27.hosting.reg.ru; Initial Catalog=u1236799_BallOSP5; User ID=*****;Password=*****");
    sqlConn.Open();
    dbAdp.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE OSP5 SET Client = @Client ", sqlConn);
    // cmd.Parameters.Add("@Client", SqlDbType.NChar, 50, "Client");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client", "Client");
    dbAdp.UpdateCommand = cmd;    
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: [Updating Data Sources with DataAdapters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters)

Comment: Во-первых, вы запутались в полях и переменных. У вас 2 `SqlCommand` - `dbAdp.UpdateCommand` и `cmd`, вы создаете одну, а присваеваете параметр другой, и ни одну из них не выполняете, во-вторых у вас отсутствует `ExecuteNonQuery()`, и в-третьих последняя ошибка - вы не закрываете соединение к базе. Чтобы не путаться - удалите глобальные поля, которые у вас за пределами методов, они вам только мешают. Когда разберетесь, как это работает, вынесете в глобальную область то, что посчитаете нужным.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, Вам нужно для начала правильно сформировать SQL запрос и выполнить его.

Как-то так:

```cs
string connectionString = "Data Source=wpl27.hosting.reg.ru; Initial Catalog=u1236799_BallOSP5; User ID=*****;Password=*****";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();    
    dbAdp.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE OSP5 SET Client = @Client ", connection);            
    dbAdp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client", "Client");
    dbAdp.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Думаю уже после этого всё должно заработать.

Comment: Дело видимо действительно в запросе. Сохранение произошло. Изменение произошло во всей таблице. Весь столбец изменился. Теперь вместо фамилии у всех клиентов стоит слово Client. Наверное dbAdp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client", "Client"); что то не то

Comment: @ЕвгенийН обновляется весь столбец потому что вы не пишете условие WHERE. Это как сказать перекрасить стены в синий, но не уточнить какие, тогда вы все стены перекрасите в синий. А если уточнить что только определенные, то остальные вы не перекрасите же

Answer (score 1):

сначала создать команду, потом добавить её в UpdateCommand:

```
private void SaveupdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=wpl27.hosting.reg.ru; Initial Catalog=u1236799_BallOSP5; User ID=*****;Password=*****");
            sqlConn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE OSP5 SET Client = @Client ", sqlConn);
            
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client", "Client");
            dbAdp.UpdateCommand = cmd;
            dbAdp.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConn.Close();
        }
```

Но у Вас скорее всего ошибка в sql запросе, полный запрос должен быть скорее всего такой:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE OSP5 SET Client = @Client WHERE ClientID = @ClientID", sqlConn);
```

по событию изменения данных о клиенте, должны меняться существующие переменные для подставляемых значение
например:

```
//string ChangedClientBody - сюда после изменения и перед обновлением бд должно записаться - Ваше - Client = @Client
//int IDChangedClient - а сюда Ваше ClientID = @ClientID;
```

далее эти переменные должны передаваться в параметры запроса:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client", ChangedClientBody);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientID", IDChangedClient);
dbAdp.UpdateCommand = cmd;
dbAdp.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConn.Close();
```

Comment: да, верно, исправил

Comment: Не сохраняет :(

Comment: составьте запрос по другому, должно присутствовать типа такого - "WHERE ClienID = @ClientID" , и Вам же надо вместо Client и ClientID - передавать конкретные значения обновляемого клиента, либо используйте dbAdp.Update(DataSet, String);

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде множество недостатков. Объяснять все не стану, т. к. это не формат нашего сайта.

Опишу лишь, как сделать вашу задачу кратчайшим способом. Как я понял, вы хотите обновить в БД те данные, которые пользователь изменил в датагриде, к которому привязан `DataTable`.

Вы используете `SqlDataAdapter` - вот его и возьмём за основу. При этом не нужны поля `SqlCommand dbCmd`, `SqlConnection sqlConn`, `SqlCommand cmd` - их просто удаляем.

Строку соединения с базой данных не стоит описывать в каждом методе. Ведь при малейшем её изменении придётся искать все эти места и исправлять. Вынесем её в поле.
Ещё лучше строку соединения читать из конфига. Но это оставим на потом.

При создании `SqlDataAdapter` нужно задать как минимум sql-запрос `select`. Это позволит получать данные из БД в `DataTable`.
А для обновления, удаления и вставки нужно, соответственно, задать sql-запросы `update`, `delete`, `insert`. Это можно сделать как вручную, так и сгенерировать автоматически с помощью класса `SqlCommandBuilder`. Он не сможет сгенерировать запросы, если селект был из нескольких таблиц с джойнами и т. п. Но в вашем случае, вероятно, справится.

Ну и всё. Далее просто используем адаптер.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string connectionString = @"тут строка соединения";

    DataTable dbTable = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter dbAdp;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();        
        
        dbAdp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from OSPS", connectionString);

        // Здесь будут сгенерированы запросы update, insert, delete
        var builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dbAdp);

        // Можно посмотреть, что там сгенерировалось
        // MessageBox.Show(builder.GetUpdateCommand().CommandText);
    }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbAdp.Fill(dbTable);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dbTable;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[7].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    }

    private void SaveUpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbAdp.Update(dbTable);
    }
}
```

Полезные ссылки:

[Updating Data Sources with DataAdapters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters)
[Generating Commands with CommandBuilders](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/generating-commands-with-commandbuilders)

И ещё. Почему не стоит использовать метод `AddWithValue`:
[Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)
[AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html)
[AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)
Достаточно прочитать любую из этих статей.

Comment: Спасибо буду разбираться

Answer (score 0):

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.bimar";
      da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
      SqlCommandBuilder cBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
      dt = new DataTable();
 
      da.Fill(dt);
 
      BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
      bSource.DataSource = dt;
 
      dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
```

когда вы изменяете свои данные в dataGridView1 , обновите их:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        da.Update(dt);
    }
```

Это решение мне помогло. Может кому-то пригодится. Теперь изменения сделанные в DatagridView сохраняются

Comment: Оно прекрасно работает и без BindingSource. Поэтому если вы не используете его дополнительные возможности, то можно без него.

Comment: Насколько я могу понять из огрызков кода, вы в разных местах запрашиваете данные из **разных таблиц**. Соответственно, нужно создавать отдельные экземпляры `SqlDataAdapter`. Предполагаю, из-за этого у вас не работал мой пример кода.

Comment: `button1_Click` - ради всего святого, не используйте имена наподобие `button1`. Ведь изначально у вас было более-менее нормальное имя `SaveButton`. Давайте говорящие имена _всем_ переменным.

Comment: button1_Click и код что выше это из форума код. У себя я все сделал как надо. Все значения поменял и  SaveButton тоже. Спасибо всем за помощь. так или иначе учусь на своих ошибках и на ваших подсказках. Чужая критика наталкивает меня на то, что надо добиваться верного кода, а не тяп-ляп. А ошибка была с моими данными но ваш код.

Answer (score -1):

```
 private void SaveupdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dbAdp = new SqlDataAdapter();
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            int IDChangedClient=0;
            string ChangedClientBody="";
            string connectionString = "Data Source=wpl27.hosting.reg.ru; Initial Catalog=u1236799_BallOSP5; User ID=*****;Password=****";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE OSP5 SET Client = @Client WHERE OSP5ID = @OSP5ID", connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client", ChangedClientBody);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OSP5ID", IDChangedClient);
                dbAdp.UpdateCommand = cmd;
                dbAdp.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

И так не сохраняет :(

Comment: Я дал вам готовое решение. Что ещё нужно?

Comment: Это ваше сообщение не является ответом. Поэтому или перенесите его в вопрос, нажав ссылку Править или удалите его.