# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Отсутствует значение для одного или нескольких требуемых параметров. C# Windows Forms + Microsoft Access

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms

Выдает ошибку в следующей функции:

```
public void Tipmat(string tipmat)
{
    connection.Open();
    command = new OleDbCommand($"SELECT * FROM Материал WHERE Тип_мат = [{tipmat}]", connection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

При вызове функции, `tipmat` принимает одно из четырех значений (Детали, Раст_жив_сырье, Горючее_сырье, Инструменты) в зависимости от того, что выбрал пользователь в комбо боксе. Функция вызывается когда пользователь меняет значение в комбо боксе.

[image: Комбо]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка появляется когда я выбираю один из элементов комбо-бокса. Проблем с постановкой информации в переменную точно нет (в переменную успевает положиться информация о выбранном мною элементе).

[image: Таблица]

Comment: Не используйте конкатенацию/интерполяцию строк для составления sql-запроса. Используйте параметризованный запрос.

Comment: Я не силён в синтаксисе Access. Разве можно строковый литерал заключать в квадратные скобки? Должны быть одинарные кавычки, не?

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, у вас ошибка в строке запроса. Попробуйте изменить свой код так:

```
    command = new OleDbCommand($"SELECT * FROM Материал WHERE Тип_мат = '{tipmat}'", connection);
```

Здесь мы просто берем в кавычки значение, передаваемое в запрос.

Comment: Не используйте конкатенацию/интерполяцию строк для составления sql-запроса. Используйте параметризованный запрос.

Comment: Ошибка теперь не выдается, но проблема в том что теперь запрос просто не срабатывает(в том плане что если я выбираю например "Деталь" и нажимаю обновить то ничего не меняется).

Comment: @КириллРахвалов - так ваш код ничего и не делает. Вы же вызываете `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: То есть стоит убрать эту строчку? Я просто немного профан в этом всем

Comment: Я убрал строчку с ExecuteNonQuery, но ничего не поменялось.

Comment: @КириллРахвалов обратите внимание на [эту страницу](https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.5.php)
ExecuteReader: выполняет sql-выражение и возвращает строки из таблицы. Подходит для sql-выражения SELECT. А значит, если вам нужен результат используйте этот метод

Comment: Через минут 30 попробую и отпишу что получилось, сейчас появились небольшие дела.

Comment: Ответ, конечно, правильный, но полностью солидарен с тем, что стоит использовать параметризованные запросы. Это гораздо безопаснее

Comment: @КириллРахвалов - ну вы же как-то данные загрузили изначально из БД? Какой код вы использовали? Либо SqlDataReader, либо SqlDataAdapter. Вот его же используйте и теперь. А ExecuteNonQuery применяется для выполнения запросов Insert, Update, Delete.

Comment: public DataTable UpdateMat()
        {
            connection.Open();
            dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * From Материал", connection);
            bufferTable.Clear();
            dataAdapter.Fill(bufferTable);
            connection.Close();
            return bufferTable;
        }

Comment: Эта функция отвечает за обновление таблицы, в ней курирует select, но когда я в него вставлял то что мне нужно, ничего не получалось

Comment: Ну, вплане я брал эту часть кода, подставлял в него свои данные(в начале статьи), и пытался вывести то что требуется, но видимо я что-то упускаю.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте параметризированные запросы - https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.9.php

После создания такого запроса (с нужными параметрами и тд), открывайте соединение, передавайте command в метод и закрывайте его.

Для конвертации полученных данных в List используйте следующий код:

```
public List<T> SqlQuery<T>(MySqlCommand command)
{
    var result = new List<T>();
    using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    var columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName).ToArray();
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var data = new object[reader.FieldCount];
        reader.GetValues(data);

        var instance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

        for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (data[i] == DBNull.Value)
                data[i] = null;

            var property = properties.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(columns[i], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

            if (property is not null)
            {
                var dataValue = Guid.TryParse(data[i].ToString(), out Guid res) is true ? res : data[i];
                property.SetValue(instance, Convert.ChangeType(dataValue, property.PropertyType));
            }
        }
        result.Add(instance);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Не забывайте открывать и закрывать соединение. Проще всего это делать, заворачивая connection в using.

Пример использования:

```
List<T> GetMaterialsByType(MySqlConnection connection, MaterialTypeEnum materialTypeEnum)
{
    using (connection)
    {
        connection.Open();

        using var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Материал WHERE Тип_мат = @MaterType";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaterType", materialTypeEnum);
        return SqlQuery(command);
    }
}

enum MaterialTypeEnum //Лучше храните одинаковые типы в enum. Гораздо проще жизнь станет
{
    Iron = 0,
    Wood = 1
}
```

UPD:

Заметил, как вы именуете методы. Слов, кроме как, "Wtf?!" не могу подобрать. Неужто нельзя назвать метод по получению списка материалов как-нибудь типо GetMaterialsByType, как у меня выше в примере.

Прошу, прочтите данную статью для приведения вашего стиля написания кода в порядок https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions

Comment: Писал без VisualStudio - просто через редактор на сайте. Поэтому могут быть опечатки в коде и тд. Если они есть, дайте знать

Comment: Ух... Имхо, опять оверинжиниринг. Автор начинающий, не поймёт-с! ЗЫ: лучше Dapper заюзать.

Comment: Не стоит использовать `AddWithValue`. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1236621/184217 - внизу ответа три ссылки на статьи

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Никто до этого не использовал Dapper. Почитаю информацию об этом обязательно. Но касаемо того, что AddWithValue - не лучший выбор - впервые слышу. Обязательно прочту статьи, которые вы приложили к ответу по ссылке. Спасибо

Comment: Спасибо конечно за проделанный код, но мне не обязательно требуется максимально эффективный код, я лишь хочу что бы у меня получилось то что делал я. Я попробовал вставить код выше, он выдает некоторые ошибки, например то что он не видит SqlQuery(command). А также ему не нравится using var, он говорит эта команда поддерживается только с версии 8.0, а у меня 7.3.

Comment: Рефакторинг и улучшение качества кода - крайне важные вещи при написании кода. Всегда нужно смотреть на свой код с точки зрения "А что за херня?" и пытаться улучшить его. Я вам дал рекомендации, как сделать это и уменьшить количество строк бессмысленных повторений. К тому же, в моём ответе содержится ответ на ваш вопрос - как сделать параметризованный запрос, который будет работать. Касаемо той ошибки - пробовали гуглить? Это ведь делается в 2 клика. Первая же ссылка - избавление от ошибки https://andrey.moveax.ru/post/csharp-version-select